# How to access all tenants and subscriptions with a single login in Azure Management SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-management-api

I'm trying to use https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net for authentication to Azure from a command-line application. My goal is to list all storage accounts in all tenants and all subscriptions using fluent libraries with no success.

`FromDevice` method is actually working well, if I use `common` as tenant ID:

```cs
AzureCredentials credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromDevice(
    AzureCliClientId,
    "common",
    AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud,
    code =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(code.Message);
        return true;
    });

IAuthenticated authenticatedAzure = Azure.Authenticate(azureNativeCreds);
```

however any call to `auth.Subscriptions.ListAsync` returns empty list of subscriptions for any account that has access to more than one tenant or more than one subscription.

I can list the tenants user belongs to with `auth.Tenants.ListAsync()` and that returns valid list of tenants, however I can't find a way to now use a particular tenant and subscription to make a subsequent call.

One way to achieve what I want is to create another instance of `IAzure` but that pops up authentication dialog again, i.e.:

```cs
foreach(var tenant in await authenticatedAzure.Tenants.ListAsync())
{
    //create creds for tenant?
    //throws authentication dialog for every tenant

    var tenantCredentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromDevice(
        AzureCliClientId,
        tenant.TenantId,
        AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud,
        code =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(code.Message);
            return true;
        });

  IAzure tenantAzure = await Azure.Authenticate(tcreds).WithDefaultSubscriptionAsync();

  var storageAccounts = await tenantAzure.StorageAccounts.ListAsync();
}
```

so the user gets constantly annoyed with popups. Another issue that `FromDevice` won't remember that the user has already logged in previously, regardless whether I save token cache to disk or not (`TokenCache.DefaultShared.BeforeWrite` etc).

Comment: Are `auth` and `tcreds` the same type? Perhaps you could just pass `auth` to `Azure.Authenticate` directly.

Comment: Sorry, updated variable naming. They are of the same type, but the first one is for `common` tenant, and the other one with specific tenant ID, so I can't substitute one for another.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, the method `Subscriptions.ListAsync` just can return the subscriptions in the user's default tenant. For example, if you use the account `xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com` to login, it will just return to the subscriptions in the tenant `xxx.onmicrosoft.com`. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list).

The details are as below. 
1. [Register the Azure AD public client application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/register-public-azure-ad-client-app)
2. Configure permissions for the Azure AD applications you use.
  [image]
  [image]

3. Code

```
var cred= SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromDevice("731373ea-9249-45aa-a7da-79c083a9d8b0", "common",AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud, code =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(code.Message);
                return true;
            });

            var azure = Azure.Authenticate(cred);
            var subs = azure.Subscriptions.List();
            foreach (var sub in subs) {

                Console.WriteLine(sub.DisplayName);
            }
```

---

### Update

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've sort of done this, the code is in my question and it works. The problem is how do you then list all subscriptions in all tenants you belong to?

Comment: @IvanG. Now, we have no way to get all subscriptions in all tenants you belong to. We just can get all subscriptions in one tenant. If we want to get all subscriptions in all tenants, we need to do that from one by one tenant

Comment: I know this is physically possible because Azure Storage Explorer does it in one login. As well as azure cli and azure powershell.

Comment: According to my test, when we use PowerShell to list the subscriptions. It will send some requests.

Comment: @IvanG. It may sdk just sends the single request at one time.

Comment: I actually don't mind how many requrests it sends to achieve the goal. The issue is how do you ask the user to log in once, say with device code, and use those credentials to connect to multiple tenants?