# Get all subscriptions in all tenants one user belongs to

Tags: .net, azure

When we use Azure CLI command `az login` with Azure account, we can get all subscriptions in all tenants the user belongs to. Now I want to implement it with Azure .net sdk. But I just can get one tenant's subscriptions. Could someone help me?

```
var cred= SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromDevice("app id", "common",AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud, code =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(code.Message);
                return true;
            });

            var azure = Azure.Authenticate(cred);
            var subs = azure.Subscriptions.List();
            foreach (var sub in subs) {

                Console.WriteLine(sub.DisplayName);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `azure.Subscriptions.List()` will just list the subscriptions in one tenant. Even if you use `common` parameter, actually it will also specify a default tenant, not all the tenant.

You could try the code as below, it lists all the tenants and calls the REST API to list all the subscriptions in every tenant that the user can access.

**Note**: The client id I used is the Microsoft Application `Microsoft Azure CLI`, you can use `04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46` directly, no need to change it to yours. Just run the code as below without changing anything.

[image]

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cred = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromDevice("04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46", "common", AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud, code =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(code.Message);
                return true;
            });

            var azure = Azure.Authenticate(cred);
            var tenants = azure.Tenants.List();

            foreach (var tenant in tenants)
            {


               string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant.TenantId;

                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
                AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", "04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46", new Uri("http://localhost:80"), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)).Result;
                //AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByDeviceCodeAsync(devcode).Result;



                using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.AccessToken);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    //GET Method  
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2019-06-01").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {

                        //Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString());
                        string myjson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();

                        JObject jo1 = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myjson);
                        string s1 = jo1["value"].ToString();

                        JArray ja2 = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s1);
                        if (ja2.Count != 0)
                        {
                            for(int i=0;i<ja2.Count;i++)
                            {
                                string j1 = ja2[i]["displayName"].ToString();
                                Console.WriteLine(j1);
                            }                            
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Internal server Error");
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @test123 Could you get it now?

Comment: I can get it. But I think we can use Azure management sdk to implement it.

Comment: @test123 No, you can't. Even if you use the powershell or cli, they return all the subscriptions, once you use the fiddler or the debug mode, you will find actually they call the list subscriptions rest api one by one in the every tenant.

Comment: @test123 If you don't trust me, I think you may trust the guy who answered your other questions several times? His opinion is the same as mine in this similar post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607479/how-to-access-all-tenants-and-subscriptions-with-a-single-login-in-azure-managem/58619230#58619230

Comment: @test123 Any other concern? If not, please accept it as answer. Anyway, I think it solved your issue.